# Proof that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}=\ln2 $?

Tags: summation

Using approximation with a spreadsheet, I see that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ 2^n} = \ln 2$$

Is there a proof of this?

Comment: This and  many more similar questions can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_1%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5C%202%5En%7D%20%3D%20%5Cln%202%24&p=1)

Comment: $ \ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} $

Answer (score 3):

Analytic functions have **Taylor series**. Around $x=0$ these are called **Maclaurin series**. For $\ln(1+x)$ specifically it is called the **Mercator series** and is given by:

$$ \ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots $$

This follows from integrating the geometric series termwise:

$$ \frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots $$

Both series are valid for (at least) $|x|<1$. Plugging $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ into the Mercator series yields

$$ \ln(1/2)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\cdot2^2}-\frac{1}{3\cdot2^3}-\frac{1}{4\cdot2^4}-\cdots $$

Multiplying by $-1$ yields $\displaystyle\ln2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$ as desired.

Comment: The Mercator series is also valid for x=1$